# Package installation with React 18 doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, types, material-ui, npm-install

when trying to install any package I come across with an error below. Please, help my to find a solution for this problem.

```js
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm ERR! Found: @types/react@18.0.31
npm ERR! node_modules/@types/react
npm ERR!   @types/react@"^18.0.31" from the root project
npm ERR!   peerOptional @types/react@"*" from @material-ui/types@5.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/types
npm ERR!     @material-ui/types@"5.1.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm ERR!     node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm ERR!       @material-ui/core@"^4.12.4" from the root project
npm ERR!     @material-ui/types@"5.1.0" from @material-ui/styles@4.11.5
npm ERR!     node_modules/@material-ui/styles
npm ERR!       @material-ui/styles@"^4.11.5" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm ERR!       node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm ERR!         @material-ui/core@"^4.12.4" from the root project
npm ERR!   9 more (@mui/base, @mui/icons-material, @mui/material, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional @types/react@"^16.8.6 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm ERR!   @material-ui/core@"^4.12.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @types/react@17.0.59
npm ERR! node_modules/@types/react
npm ERR!   peerOptional @types/react@"^16.8.6 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm ERR!     @material-ui/core@"^4.12.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

My package.json:
https://github.com/orchidenver/weather-app-react/blob/test/package.json

Comment: You shouldn’t be including v4 of MUI. It isn’t compatible with React 18 and you’re already including v5 of MUI.

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to install material ui v4 which is not compatible with react 18.  Material UI v5 is the only version that fully supports React 18, so you'll need to update to mui 5

first uninstall **@material-ui/core v4**

then install mui5 :  `npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled`

Comment: Already tried to apply this solution. Unfortunately I have the same error.

Comment: @SevaSleva That’s because you still have v4 in your package.json (`"@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",`). You need to remove it.